# How to properly install prophet with python 3.9.13

Tags: python-3.9, facebook-prophet, prophet

The current pystan==2.19.1.1, and it seems that this's the highest version in python 3.9.

I have tried:

1. pip install prophet. Using this command I can install the prophet but when running fit I got errors. Error: Unexpected exception formatting exception. Falling back to standard exception.
2. pip install fbprophet. couldn't install it.
3. conda install -c "conda-forge/label/broken" prophet. Using this command I can install the prophet but when running fit I got errors again. Error: 'StanModel' object has no attribute 'fit_class'.

I have tried everything I can find online so far but still couldn't solve the problem, and unfortunately I can't change my python version cause I need this particular one to install keras and tensorflow in mac M1 system.

Comment: have you tried to do `--no-cache-dir` on install pystan and prophet?

Comment: where should I run this line? in the terminal or the jupyter cell? Btw, my whole conda crashed, not just the virtual environment, I will reply to you after I fixed the conda environment.

Comment: it would be `pip install prophet --no-cache-dir`

Comment: So I removed everything and installed miniconda following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5DgWvU0p2bk&t=56s. After that I installed pystan(2.19.1.1,), and then pip install fbprophet, and now it's working! I really don't know why it's working now.